# POST WEB API retorna NULL

Tags: api, null, postman

Estou iniciando meus estudos com API REST e seguindo um tutorial da Internet desenvolvi esta API :

Classe :

```
namespace SimpleRESTServer.Models
```

{
    public class Person
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public String   LastName { get; set; }
        public String FisrtName { get; set; }
        public Double PayRate { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
}

Controller :

```
namespace SimpleRESTServer.Controllers
```

{
    public class PersonController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Person
        public IEnumerable Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "Person1", "Person2", "É nois Mano" };
        }

```
    // GET: api/Person/5
    public Person Get(int id)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.ID = id;
        person.LastName = "Da Silva";
        person.FisrtName = "Eduardo";
        person.PayRate = 45.54;
        person.StartDate = DateTime.Parse("5/5/2019");
        person.EndDate = DateTime.Parse("5/10/2019");

        return person;
    }

    // POST: api/Person
    public void Post([FromBody]Person value)
    {
        //PersonPersistence pp = new PersonPersistence();
        //long id;
        //id = pp.savePerson(value);
    }

    // PUT: api/Person/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/Person/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

}

E Estou usando o POSTMAN para testa-la e preencho o POSTMAN conforme a tela abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ocorre que as informações não estão chegando no Controller quando faço o debug do conteúdo ele está sempre NULL

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem tem alguma ideia do pode estar errado..???

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tá enviando dados pela URL, nesse caso ai você precisaria usar a Annotation [FromUri] ao invés da [FromBody].

Creio que você esteja fazendo os testes errados pelo Postman, recomendo usar o RAW e escrever o seu json na mão.

Comment: Obrigado Carlos. Alterei para [FromUri] conforme você sugeriu e funcionou.